# from_addr = email.utils.getaddresses([from_addr])[0][1] , error while sending the email using python

Tags: python-3.x, email, smtplib

Getting below error while sending the email using python, do I need to create object?

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

email = EmailMessage()
email['from']: 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
email['to']: "xxxxx@gmail.com"
email['subject']: 'Hey Buddy Python'

email.set_content("Learning python")

with smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port="587") as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login("xxxx@gmail.com", "xxxx")
    smtp.send_message(email)
```

Output of the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/PYTHON/PyCharm/Email/SendEmail.py", line 15, in <module>
    smtp.send_message(email)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 940, in send_message
    from_addr = email.utils.getaddresses([from_addr])[0][1]
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\utils.py", line 112, in getaddresses
    all = COMMASPACE.join(fieldvalues)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting `NoneType` instead of `string` is because you are not assigning the values to the email dictionary as seen in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html).

More specifically, here:

```
email['from']: 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
email['to']: "xxxxx@gmail.com"
email['subject']: 'Hey Buddy Python'
```

Instead of `:` you should use the assign operator, `=`.

Try with:

```
email['from'] = 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
email['to'] = "xxxxx@gmail.com"
email['subject'] ='Hey Buddy Python'
```